# Load a frame from another class file in tkinter

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, frame

I have this code in tkinter, all in one file, where I have a main window that has a frame as a menu and another frame that is the main screen. The menu calls other frames that are defined with their respective content. What I want to do is to pass each one of these frames, as `inicio_page()` to another file so that the code is not so long and also to be able to call them to the main file and that it is still functional.

Actually an example would be like this

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Test")

        app_width = 1300
        app_height = 720

        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width /2) - (app_width / 2)
        y = (screen_height /3) - (app_height / 3)

        self.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")

        self.minsize(width=1300, height=720)
        self.maxsize(width=1920, height=1080)

        backg = PhotoImage(file="img/trineside.png")
        backg1 = PhotoImage(file="img/prueba4.png")

        def delete_pages():
            for frame in main_frame.winfo_children():
                frame.destroy()

        def indicate(lb, page):
            hide_indicators()
            lb.config(bg="white")
            delete_pages()
            page()

        def hide_indicators():
            page1_indicate.config(bg="#124e6b")
            page2_indicate.config(bg="#124e6b")


        menu_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#124e6b", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)

        menu_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        menu_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        menu_frame.configure(width=195, height=1020)

        background_menuframe= Label(menu_frame, image=backg)
        background_menuframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        inicio_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page1", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b", padx=56, activebackground='#124e6b', command=lambda: indicate(page1_indicate, inicio_page))
        inicio_btn.place(x=10, y=100)

        page1_indicate = tk.Label(menu_frame, text="", bg="#124e6b")
        page1_indicate.place(x=3, y=100, width=5, height=43)

        #########################################################

        clientes_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page2", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b",padx=40, command=lambda: indicate(page2_indicate, page_2))
        clientes_btn.place(x=10, y=150)

        page2_indicate = tk.Label(menu_frame, text="", bg="#124e6b")
        page2_indicate.place(x=3, y=150, width=5, height=43)

        #########################################################

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        background_mainframe= Label(main_frame, image=backg1)
        background_mainframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        main_frame.configure(height=1020, width=1750)

        lb = tk.Label(main_frame, text="Try", font=("bold", 50))
        lb.pack(pady=100)
 
        def inicio_page():
            background_mainframe= Label(main_frame, image=backg1)
            background_mainframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            inicio_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
            titulo_principal = tk.Label(main_frame,text="INICIO", font=("Bold", 15), bg="#031f3f", fg="white", height="2")
            titulo_principal.pack(fill=tk.X)
            inicio_frame.pack(pady=80)

            #frames
            f1_frame = tk.Frame(inicio_frame, bg="yellow", width=600, height=150)
            f1_frame.pack()

            f2_frame = tk.Frame(inicio_frame, width=500, height=400)
            f2_frame.pack()

            box1 = tk.Frame(f2_frame, height=20,width=250)
            box1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
            box2 = tk.Frame(f2_frame, height=20,width=250)
            box2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        
    
            btn_logs = Button(box1,text="Abrir Logs",width=18)
            btn_logs.pack(pady=20,padx=80)

            btn_informes = Button(box2,text="Abrir Informes", width=18)
            btn_informes.pack(pady=20,padx=80)

            textof1 = Label(f1_frame, text="")
            textof1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

What I did was to pass the `inicio_page()` function to another file and modify the button command to call the new class. My problem is that when I click on the button it does not show me the content that is in the `InicioPage` class.

I leave an example of what I tried.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from frame_inicio import InicioPage

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Test")

        app_width = 1300
        app_height = 720

        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width /2) - (app_width / 2)
        y = (screen_height /3) - (app_height / 3)

        self.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")

        self.minsize(width=1300, height=720)
        self.maxsize(width=1920, height=1080)

        backg = PhotoImage(file="img/trineside.png")
        backg1 = PhotoImage(file="img/prueba4.png")

        def delete_pages():
            for frame in main_frame.winfo_children():
                frame.destroy()

        menu_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#124e6b", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)

        menu_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        menu_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        menu_frame.configure(width=195, height=1020)

        background_menuframe= Label(menu_frame, image=backg)
        background_menuframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        inicio_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Inicio", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b", padx=56, activebackground='#124e6b', command=lambda: delete_pages() and InicioPage(main_frame))
        inicio_btn.place(x=10, y=100)

        page1_indicate = tk.Label(menu_frame, text="", bg="#124e6b")
        page1_indicate.place(x=3, y=100, width=5, height=43)

        #########################################################

        clientes_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page2", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b",padx=40, command=lambda: indicate(page2_indicate, page_2))
        clientes_btn.place(x=10, y=150)

        page2_indicate = tk.Label(menu_frame, text="", bg="#124e6b")
        page2_indicate.place(x=3, y=150, width=5, height=43)

        #########################################################

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        background_mainframe= Label(main_frame, image=backg1)
        background_mainframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        main_frame.configure(height=1020, width=1750)

        lb = tk.Label(main_frame, text="Try", font=("bold", 50))
        lb.pack(pady=100)
```

frame_inicio.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class InicioPage:
    def __init__(self, main_frame):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)

        backg1 = PhotoImage(file="img/prueba4.png")

        background_mainframe= Label(main_frame, image=backg1)
        background_mainframe.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        inicio_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
        titulo_principal = tk.Label(main_frame,text="INICIO", font=("Bold", 15), bg="#031f3f", fg="white", height="2")
        titulo_principal.pack(fill=tk.X)
        inicio_frame.pack(pady=80)

        #frames
        f1_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame, bg="yellow", width=600, height=150)
        f1_frame.pack()

        f2_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=400)
        f2_frame.pack()

        box1 = tk.Frame(f2_frame, height=20,width=250)
        box1.grid(row=0, column=0)
     
        box2 = tk.Frame(f2_frame, height=20,width=250)
        box2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        btn_logs = Button(box1,text="Abrir Logs",width=18)
        btn_logs.pack(pady=20,padx=80)

        btn_informes = Button(box2,text="Abrir Informes", width=18)
        btn_informes.pack(pady=20,padx=80)
```

Comment: For the expression `delete_pages() and InicioPage(main_frame)` , `InicioPage(...)` will never be executed because `delete_pages()` return `None`.  Change `and` to `or`.

Comment: line 49, in <lambda>
    clientes_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page2", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b",padx=40, command=lambda: indicate(page2_indicate, page_2))
                                                                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'indicate' is not defined

Comment: Change  command=lambda: InicioPage(page2_indicate) instead of indicate.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't instantiating the class `InicioPage` anywhere I can see. You'll need to create an instance of `InicioPage` with the desired parent like so:

```
from frame_inicio import InicioPage


...  # other code has been omitted for brevity

# FYI, widgets that are defined within a class should be prefixed with 'self.'
# e.g.: 'self.main_frame = tk.Frame', 'self.main_frame.pack()', etc.
main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
self.start_page = InicioPage(main_frame)  # instantiate the class object to use it
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the expression `delete_pages() and InicioPage(main_frame)`, `InicioPage(main_frame)` will never be executed because `delete_pages()` returns `None` which is evaluated as `False` in the expression.

Either return `True` from `delete_pages()` or change `and` to `or` in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Got from @JRiggles's example.

In line 49 change this:

```
clientes_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page2", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b",padx=40, command=lambda: InicioPage(page2_indicate))
```

to:

```
clientes_btn = tk.Button(menu_frame, text="Page2", font=("Bold", 18), fg="white", bd=0, bg="#124e6b",padx=40, command=lambda: InicioPage(main_frame))
```

frame_inicio.py.

Add this `self.frame.mainloop()` to bottom

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot when pressed page 2 button:

[image]

Comment: Followed @acw1668 about  delete_pages().